# Web scraping blank results

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to load data but it returns empty list, not sure what is going wrong here... I am adding the same script which I found from other tutorials

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import pandas as pd

url = ' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table'

result = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.title)

content = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter')

print(content)
```

Comment: Are that class and tables available on that URL?

Comment: It seems that the given URL doesn't contain any table.

Answer (score 2):

*Answer based on the Updated URL.*

You are selecting all the tables using `find_all()`. In the URL, you need to select only the medals table and not all.

You can select the medals table with `content.find('table', class_='wikitable')`.

Here I have pulled all the `<tr>`s from the table and stored them in `trs` variable. You can iterate over `trs` list and extract the data you need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table'

result = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')
trs = content.findAll('tr')
```

Comment: but it doesn't get me the tables which I need which I need to use for analytics

Comment: What tables ? Where do you see tables in that web page ?

Comment: sorry, the url was different... I used api endpoint in my question..  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table

Comment: Please update your question with the correct URL. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Ram... I have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`print(soup)` shows that `url` was scraped successfully. The error is on the `content = ...` line - the given url contains no `table`. Here's the `print(soup)` output:

> {"type":"standard","title":"Summer Olympic Games","displaytitle":"Summer Olympic Games","namespace":{"id":0,"text":""},"wikibase_item":"Q159821","titles":{"canonical":"Summer_Olympic_Games","normalized":"Summer Olympic Games","display":"Summer Olympic Games"},"pageid":27566,"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg/320px-Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg.png","width":320,"height":148},"originalimage":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg/342px-Olympic_rings_without_rims.svg.png","width":342,"height":158},"lang":"en","dir":"ltr","revision":"1035750198","tid":"667065b0-eedc-11eb-83d5-e721135a5a1e","timestamp":"2021-07-27T13:12:59Z","description":"International multi-sport event","description_source":"local","content_urls":{"desktop":{"page":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games","revisions":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games?action=history","edit":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games?action=edit","talk":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Summer_Olympic_Games"},"mobile":{"page":"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games","revisions":"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:History/Summer_Olympic_Games","edit":"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games?action=edit","talk":"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Summer_Olympic_Games"}},"extract":"The Summer Olympic Games, also known as the Games of the Olympiad, are a major international multi-sport event normally held once every four years. The Games were first held in 1896 in Athens, Greece, and are currently being held in 2021 in Tokyo, Japan. The International Olympic Committee (IOC) organises the Games and oversees the host city's preparations. In each Olympic event, gold medals are awarded for first place, silver medals are awarded for second place, and bronze medals are awarded for third place; this tradition began in 1904. The Winter Olympic Games were created out of the success of the Summer Olympics.","extract_html":"
>
> The **Summer Olympic Games**, also known as the **Games of the Olympiad**, are a major international multi-sport event normally held once every four years. The Games were first held in 1896 in Athens, Greece, and are currently being held in 2021 in Tokyo, Japan. The International Olympic Committee (IOC) organises the Games and oversees the host city's preparations. In each Olympic event, gold medals are awarded for first place, silver medals are awarded for second place, and bronze medals are awarded for third place; this tradition began in 1904. The Winter Olympic Games were created out of the success of the Summer Olympics.
>
> "}

Comment: I need those tables by country for analytics